# How to audit the selinux denial inside a docker container

Tags: docker, selinux

I have a docker container, when disable selinux, it works well;
but when enabled selinux (i.e. the docker daemon is started with --selinux-enabled), it can not start up.

So the failure should caused by selinux denial, but this is not shown in the selinux audit log. when I use the "ausearch -m XXX | audit2allow ..." to generate the policy, it does not include any denial info.

want to know how to get the selinux denial info occured inside the container, so that I can use it in generating my policy file?

ps: I checked the label info of the accessed file, they seem right,but access(ls) is denied:

```
# ls -dlZ /usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c380,c857 /usr/bin
# ls /usr/bin
ls: cannot open directory /usr/bin: Permission denied
```

more: the selected answer answered the question, but now the problem is the audit log shows the access is to read "unlabeled_t", but as the "ls -dZ /usr/bin" shows, it is a "container_file_t". I put this in a separate question:
[Why SELinux denies access to container internal files and claims them as "unlabled_t"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397387/why-selinux-denies-access-to-container-internal-files-and-claims-them-as-unlabl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The policy likely contains *dontaudit* rules. *Dontaudit* rules do not allow acecss, but suppress logging for the specific access.

You can disable *dontaudit* rules with `semanage`:

```
semanage dontaudit off
```

After solving the issue, you probably want to turn the *dontaudit* rules back on to reduce log noise.

It is also possible to search for possible *dontaudit* rules with `sesearch`:

```
sesearch --dontaudit -t container_file_t
```