# Why SELinux denies access to container internal files and claims them as "unlabled_t"?

Tags: docker, access-denied, selinux

This is related to this question:
[How to audit the selinux denial inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323516/how-to-audit-the-selinux-denial-inside-a-docker-container)

I have a container that does not work after enforcing selinux, the "ls /app" command failed with access denial:

```
# docker exec -it XXX ls -lZ /app
ls: cannot open directory /app: Permission denied
```

the first problem is that selinux denial messages not logged for accessing inside my container,after turnoff the "dontaudit", the selinux denial info appears, but it shows the container is trying to "read" an "unlabeled_t",

> ```
> type=AVC msg=audit(1537323105.938:115360): avc:  denied  { read } for  
> pid=11891 comm="ls" path="/app" dev="vdb" ino=917696
> scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c136,c536
> tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=dir
> ```

but per the below info, it is of "container_file_t"

```
# docker exec -it XXX ls -dZ /app
       drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c136,c536 /app
```

I don't think it is proper that I add a rule to allow (container_t read  "unlabeled_t" dir), though it does work.

So I want to know why the "/app" dir(and many others) inside the container deemed as "unlabeled_t" by the SELinux, and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: [How to enable SELinux inside of a CentOS Docker container?](https://serverfault.com/questions/757606/how-to-enable-selinux-inside-of-a-centos-docker-container#757609)

Comment: the /app inside the container does not exist in the host filesystem, do you mean I need/can change the host filesystem label rules to fix the problem?

Comment: relabiling inside the app container to have the same label as the host `/` might work.

Comment: label of host / is "root_t", and exec "chcon -R -t root_t /" inside the container can't  succeed.

Comment: This is same container in both `ls` examples?

Comment: Yes, it is the same container